# Detecting outliers in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, outliers

Dataframe:

```
                     oph_single_positive_outlier  oph_single_negative_outlier  oph_1pos_1neg_outlier  oph_multipos_at_once_outlier
bucket
2023-01-01 00:05:00                            1                            1                      1                             1
2023-01-01 00:06:00                            2                            2                     10                            10
2023-01-01 00:07:00                            3                            3                      3                            10
2023-01-01 00:08:00                           10                            2                      2                            10
2023-01-01 00:09:00                            4                            4                      4                             4
2023-01-01 00:10:00                            5                            5                      5                             5
```

How to remove outliers? Examples:

- In `oph_single_positive_outlier` value 10.
- In `oph_single_negative_outlier` fourth row should be deleted.
- In `oph_1pos_1neg_outlier` second row (10) and fourth (2).

Basically all rows that are decreasing or rapidly increase. I should get a graph for every column. My code:

```
orig_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set the 'bucket' column as the index
orig_df.set_index('bucket', inplace=True)
print("orignal DataFrame")
display(orig_df)

# Remove invalid data
orig_df = orig_df.dropna()
outliers_single_df = pd.DataFrame()

column= "oph_single_negative_outlier"
columns = orig_df.columns
df = orig_df.pop(columns[0]).to_frame()
df_len_at_start = df.shape[0]
while (True):
    df['DifferencePumping'] = pd.to_timedelta(df[columns[0]].diff(), unit="h")
    df['DifferencePumpingShifted'] = df['DifferencePumping'].shift(-1)
    df['bucket'] = df.index

    df['DifferenceBucket'] = df["bucket"].diff()
    df['DifferenceBucketShifted'] = df['DifferenceBucket'].shift(-1)

    df["decreasing"] = df["DifferencePumping"] < pd.Timedelta(0)
    df["rapid_increase"] = df["DifferenceBucketShifted"] < df["DifferencePumpingShifted"] - pd.Timedelta(seconds=6)

    df["potential_outliers"] = df.decreasing | df.rapid_increase

    try:
        outliers_single_df = pd.concat([outliers_single_df, df.loc[df.potential_outliers].head(1)])
        df = df.drop(df.loc[df.potential_outliers].index[0])

    except IndexError as index_error:
        df = df.drop(columns=['DifferencePumping', 'DifferencePumpingShifted', "bucket", "DifferenceBucket", "DifferenceBucketShifted", "decreasing", "rapid_increase", "potential_outliers"])

        print("Filtered all outliers.")
        break
```

Output:

```
Filtered all outliers.
                     oph_single_positive_outlier
bucket
2023-01-01 00:08:00                           10

Removed outliers:
                     oph_single_positive_outlier DifferencePumping DifferencePumpingShifted              bucket DifferenceBucket DifferenceBucketShifted  decreasing  rapid_increase  potential_outliers
bucket
2023-01-01 00:05:00                            1               NaT          0 days 01:00:00 2023-01-01 00:05:00              NaT         0 days 00:01:00       False            True                True
2023-01-01 00:06:00                            2               NaT          0 days 01:00:00 2023-01-01 00:06:00              NaT         0 days 00:01:00       False            True                True
2023-01-01 00:07:00                            3               NaT          0 days 07:00:00 2023-01-01 00:07:00              NaT         0 days 00:01:00       False            True                True
2023-01-01 00:09:00                            4 -1 days +18:00:00          0 days 01:00:00 2023-01-01 00:09:00  0 days 00:01:00         0 days 00:01:00        True            True                True
2023-01-01 00:10:00                            5 -1 days +19:00:00                      NaT 2023-01-01 00:10:00  0 days 00:02:00                     NaT        True           False                True

Original df
                     oph_single_negative_outlier  oph_1pos_1neg_outlier  oph_multipos_at_once_outlier
bucket
2023-01-01 00:05:00                            1                      1                             1
2023-01-01 00:06:00                            2                     10                            10
2023-01-01 00:07:00                            3                      3                            10
2023-01-01 00:08:00                            2                      2                            10
2023-01-01 00:09:00                            4                      4                             4
2023-01-01 00:10:00                            5                      5                             5

cleaned df
                     oph_single_positive_outlier
bucket
2023-01-01 00:08:00                           10

Deleted 5 rows.
```

Comment: When there is an outlier in one column only, do you want the whole row removed (all columns) or just the outlier?  In the latter case, do you want the outlier replaced by NaN?  (It would help if you showed the desired result).

Answer (score 0):

is there any specific reason that you want to use rapid increses/ decrease method vs. IQR method to remove outliers? I think the results would be the same for this small dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['bucket'] = pd.to_datetime(df['bucket'])
df.set_index('bucket', inplace=True)

# IQR method
def remove_outliers_iqr(df, column_name, multiplier=1.5):
    q1 = df[column_name].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df[column_name].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    lower_bound = q1 - multiplier * iqr
    upper_bound = q3 + multiplier * iqr
    return df[(df[column_name] >= lower_bound) & (df[column_name] <= upper_bound)]

columns_to_process = df.columns

for column in columns_to_process:
    df = remove_outliers_iqr(df, column)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your code, but if your rule for outlier detection is determined by the change in the value from one sample to the next, then you can write a [custom ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) to govern the keep/replace decision, and use [numpy.ufunc.accumulate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) to iterate over the values from your dataframe, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454357/iterating-and-accumulating-over-a-numpy-array-with-a-custom-function).

```
def remove_outliers(xm1, x):
    diff = x - xm1
    if diff >= 0 and diff < 5:
        return x
    else:
        return xm1

ufunc = np.frompyfunc(remove_outliers, 2, 1)

# Check it works
assert ufunc(1, 2) == 2  # not an outlier
assert ufunc(1, 0) == 1  # an outlier
assert ufunc(1, 6) == 1  # an outlier

new_values = ufunc.accumulate(orig_df.values, dtype=float)
df = pd.DataFrame(new_values, index=orig_df.index, columns=orig_df.columns)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    oph_single_positive_outlier oph_single_negative_outlier oph_1pos_1neg_outlier oph_multipos_at_once_outlier
2023-01-01 00:05:00                           1                           1                     1                            1
2023-01-01 00:06:00                           2                           2                     1                            1
2023-01-01 00:07:00                           3                           3                     3                            1
2023-01-01 00:08:00                           3                           3                     3                            1
2023-01-01 00:09:00                           4                           4                     4                            4
2023-01-01 00:10:00                           5                           5                     5                            5
```